# making form inline with a picture in a row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to do something like this
[image]

So I did the following

```css
.page-account-box {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.page-account-box .ds-userlogin .account-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #e2efef;
  position: relative;
  margin: 70px auto 30px;
  display: table;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.page-account-box .ds-userlogin .account-box .picture_account {
  display: inline;
  width: 50%;
}

.page-account-box .ds-userlogin .account-box .account-box-content {
  min-height: 50%;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="page-account-box">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12 mx-auto">
        <div class="ds-userlogin">
          <div class="account-box">
            <div class="picture_account"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" class="imgFormat" /></div>
            <div class="account-box-content">
              <form method="post" class="form-account form-inline ">
                <div class="form-account-title">
                  <input type="text" style="border:solid" id="FullName">
                  <label for="email-phone">Fullname</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-account-title">
                  <input type="password" style="border:solid" id="Password">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row-account">
                  <a onclick="Registeruser()" class="btn btn-primary btn-register">Register  </a>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the result would be like this
[image]
how can I make the forms be inline with the picture?

Answer (score 2):

> how can I make the forms be inline with the picture?

Remove your CSS and in your HTML replace `account-box`:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="account-box row">
  <div class="account-box-content col">
    <form method="post" class="form-account form-inline ">
      <div class="form-account-title">
        <input type="text" style="border:solid" id="FullName">
        <label for="email-phone">Fullname</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-account-title">
        <input type="password" style="border:solid" id="Password">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row-account">
        <a onclick="Registeruser()" class="btn btn-primary btn-register">Register  </a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="picture_account col">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" class="imgFormat" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The class of `row` to turn the container holding your image and form into a row, and the class of `col` on both your form and image to put them on separate columns. Also your image is now below the form in the markup so it appears on the left visually.

Comment: @tacoshy Is this better?

Comment: Well first the OP uses Bootstrap and as such Bootstrap should be used. If it is better to use vanilla CSS or a framework is completely opinion-based. Your recommendation most-likely will not be practicable as proberly the entire website is using the framework not just that single form. Also often it is a task from the company or customer. As such questions specifically labeld with a framework should also use that framework. However, your question could be greatly improved if you use the OP's code and a [repro]

Comment: @tacoshy Bootstrap now used, and opinions removed. Any more feedback?

Comment: like I said, use a [repro] with the `<>`-Button or by pressing `Ctrl+M` when you add code. If frameworks are used, add the dependency too (I just did that for you). So the code can be run and directly validate your answer. As such your answer now fulfills all criteria for a good answer. It is technical correct, on-topic, validates and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following to your account-box-content class:

```
 float: left;
```

Here's a fiddle you can see it working on: https://jsfiddle.net/gx3y8ksc/

Comment: answer is way to broad. Use the comment option if you want to push the Op in a certain direction. The answer option is for a definite solution that preferably should be validated with a working code example. The code example must be included directly in the answer itself to be self-containing. External resources may only be used as extension but never as standalone!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.page-account-box {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.page-account-box .ds-userlogin .account-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #e2efef;
  position: relative;
  margin: 70px auto 30px;
  display: table;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.page-account-box .ds-userlogin .account-box .picture_account {
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-account-box .ds-userlogin .account-box .account-box-content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
.page-account-box .ds-userlogin .account-box .account-box-content form {
  width: 100%;
}
.page-account-box
  .ds-userlogin
  .account-box
  .account-box-content
  form
  .form-account-title {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.page-account-box
  .ds-userlogin
  .account-box
  .account-box-content
  form
  .form-account-title
  input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="page-account-box">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12 mx-auto">
        <div class="ds-userlogin">
          <div class="account-box">

            <div class="account-box-content">
              <form method="post" class="form-account form-inline ">
                <div class="form-account-title">
                  <input type="text" style="border:solid" id="FullName">
                  <label for="email-phone">Fullname</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-account-title">
                  <input type="password" style="border:solid" id="Password">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row-account d-flex justify-content-center w-100">
                  <a onclick="Registeruser()" class="btn btn-primary btn-register">Register </a>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="picture_account"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" class="imgFormat" /></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```